# Symfony security loads wrong entity repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem where Symfony does'nt fetch the corrent EntityRepository in the security componenet.

Symfony returns `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider` instead of `AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository`...

My configuration looks like this:

```
providers:
    database_users:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: mobile }
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
```

And to test it, I run this code:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $repo1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:User");

    $userProvider = $this->get("security.user.provider.concrete.our_db_provider");


    $data = [
        'Hello' => 'world',
        'doctrine' => get_class($repo1),
        'security' => get_class($userProvider),
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

Which returns this:

```
{
"Hello": "world",
"doctrine": "AppBundle\\Repository\\UserRepository",
"security": "Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Security\\User\\EntityUserProvider"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Also, firwalls:

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~

        logout:
            path:   logout
            invalidate_session: false

        guard:
            provider: our_db_provider
            authenticators: [app.form_login_authenticator]
            entry_point: app.form_login_authenticator
```

Comment: Can you explain your actual issue? The `EntityUserProvider` class from the DoctrineBridge will internally use your custom entity repository for your user entity. So the tests you did in your controller are not really meaningful.

Comment: Hi! Yeah, thats the problem, it dosn't.  I have a custom loadUserByUsername that is never called....

Comment: Actually, you are right, the problem was that my repository was implementing `UserProviderInterface` instead of `UserLoaderInterface`

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but mine was to create a service for for the User repository, and use this in the user providers...

```
   app.user_repository:
     class: AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository
     factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
     arguments:
       - AppBundle:User
```

And my new user provider:

```
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        id: app.user_repository
```

If anyone can actually solve the problem, I would be happy to accept that answer :)

## Real solution

The Actuall problem was that I implemented `UserProviderInterface` instead of `UserLoaderInterface`. Also the *property*  must not be set in `security.yml`.